# Ubuntu 20.04 won't boot on ASUS A15 TUF506Q Laptop

Tags: boot, 20.04, nvidia

I installed 20.04 on a new "ASUS TUF Gaming A15 TUF506QE-MS74 15.6" Laptop Computer Platinum Collection" from a USB device I created a week ago. (Successfully installed the Ubuntu system on a new desktop system after about 6 hours of figuring it out by reading some of these forum posts specific to my model. I wanted a better computer so I just bought the laptop.)

When I boot after Laptop Installation I get the Grub menu. After selecting "Ubuntu" and attempting to continue startup I get this message:

**[ 0.493841] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\TZ.THRM._SCP.C
TYP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20201113/psargs-330)
[ 0.495899] ACPI Error: Aborting Method _TZ.THRM._SCP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20201113/psparse-529)
[ 0.938408] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (b77000a1)**

Laptop Specs are:
AMD Ryzen 7 5800H 3.0GHz Processor
NVIDIA GeForce 3050 Ti 4GB GDDR6
16GB DDR4-3200 RAM
512GB Solid State Drive

Windows is wiped out now - on purpose.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

FYI: Won't be able to check back here for another 10 hours.

Comment: Try the safe graphics mode and don't forget to check the option to install 3rd party drivers. Clearly `nouveau` doesn't yet support such a new Nvidia chipset.

Comment: Title says Ubuntu 20. Question says 20.04 and no tag set. What version is it?

Comment: Installed was 20.04.2 LTS. It's now updated to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I'm not quite sure but I think it's working okay with the update.

Comment: So I selected the second option in the Grub Menu to boot in a recovery mode. (First line below Ubuntu.) After doing that I was able to do the traditional login and get to the desktop. 
After logging in I got a notice for a software update and installed that to make it Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS . Restarted after the update and I seem to be running okay. I'll come back to this thread if I discover something unexpected.
The advice got me started down the right path! Thx

Comment: Title says Ubuntu 20 question says 20.04. Many wont look past the title.